# Error:(58, 35) error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FragmentActivity

Tags: android

Android beginner, struggling with Activity and AppCompatActivity classes. I am using Activity class in my Drawer Activity, so I have tried to use Activity class for my MainActivity, but I get the following error:

> Error:(58, 35) error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FragmentActivity

The following code gives an alert on the 'this' keyword - Wrong 1st argument. Found: 'com.*domain*.*project*.MainActivity', required: 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity'

```
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

How can I allow this section to run while still maintaining extending the Activity class?

Comment: `FragmentActivity` extends `Activity`. Why don't you want to extend `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: or `AppCompatActivity`?

Answer (score 2):

`enableAutoManage()` requires a `FragmentActivity` or some subclass of that, such as `AppCompatActivity`. You cannot use `enableAutoManage()` with a regular `Activity`. Either:

- Switch your code to use `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`, or
- Do not call `enableAutoManage()`

Comment: Used FragmentActivity and solved the problem. Thanks for your help!